# How can I separate column values in to column names?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

Im trying to make a table with dynamic columns.

I have this table. This is just simplified, in other instances these may have more values instead of 3.

```
         name         
----------------------
 Fall
 Medication 
 Wander
(3 rows)
```

I am trying to get this result. I need to separate the values into columns.

```
  Fall  | Medication | Wander 
--------+------------+--------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: so this query will return the first value "Fall". what exactly you want. you can use a[2] and a[3] to get the other values

Comment: I dont want it to return the value. would want it to return the value as a column name.

Comment: you can add commas to the value like ''' || a[1]|| '''. it will return 'Fall'

Comment: Yes I know Ive tried that but i cant  use these "a[1]" because there are instances that there are more values. These should be dynamic not constant

Comment: then you should go for a function and make a loop in that

Answer (score 0):

You need to PIVOT the table. Unfortunately MySQL (unlike Oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) doesn't have a PIVOT operator, but there are workarounds it seems. [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: The question is about Postgres, not MySQL (but Postgres doesn't have pivot either)

Comment: Looks like @prinsarian might have the answer you're looking for. crosstab() does look like the function you're looking for

Comment: @leonardseymore tried crosstab but I still have to name the columns for that. So this is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

You might try one of the crosstab() functions in newer PostgreSQL. See [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) (F.35.1.2 and F.35.1.4). It allowes you to specify a query that has row-names (those create rows), categories (that create columns) and values (that populate the inside part of the table.

The variant with 2 queries can be especially useful since it allows you to specify the columns you want to use with a seperate query.

Comment: (i'm assuming your question is about the PostgreSQL database and a fairly recent version)

Comment: Yes but you will have to declare the column names. SELECT * FROM crosstab('...') AS ct(row_name text, category_1 text, category_2 text);